# Getting a long gap between a textView and an imageView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am new to Layout Design. I had created a scrolling View and added some Textview and ImageView. There is not issues with the textview but there is a long gap between the textview and the ImageView.

details_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="#Step 1:-"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:text="Choose phone Information"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/phoneinfo"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
                />

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="#Step 2:-"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageview1"
            />


        </RelativeLayout>



    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Check the design output

[image]

What Changes should I bring for reducing this gap??

Comment: You can remove the root LinearLayout and make your ScrollView the root; then you can have a LinearLayout inside the ScrollView (ONLY 1 child) then use weights to position your items inside it

Comment: I changed to Linearlayout inside Scrollview(root)  But how to add weights. Now it looks like terrible design and textview3 is missing..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="#Step 1:-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:text="Choose phone Information" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/phoneinfo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="#Step 2:-" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: NO there is no change.